# play framework insert email footer

Tags: java, email, playframework

How can I modify email content before sending it, e.g. my program reads from email template file (text file) and passes some variables into this template and then sends but I want to add email footer every time before sending an email ( I don't want to write it into template text file ). How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like an interesting question. I guess it would be useful to add some brief bare bones code how you are doing this now (to understand better which template and email sending APIs you are using)  and explain why editing the templates is not viable to you.

Comment: How about adding a placeholder to each template and the string-replace that? Everything else sounds a lot like parsing unless you always want to append the footer at the end. In any case, I don't really see the correlation with the play framework here - this seems more like a general question.